# Counter example for: If $f\colon \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ lower semi continuous, then $\forall x_n\to x, \lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)\geq f(x)$

Tags: calculus, analysis, continuity, examples-counterexamples, semicontinuous-functions

We start with a definition.

> We say that a function $f\colon \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ is **lower semi continuous (l.s.c.)** if $$\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^n,\; \liminf_{y\to x}f(y)\geq f(x).$$

As homework, I was assigned to prove that

> $f$ is l.s.c. iff $\; \forall x_n\to x,\; \lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)\geq f(x)$ $\qquad(*)$.

yet I came up with the following counter example which shows that *there exists a $f\colon\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ l.s.c. and $x_n\to x$ such that there is no $l$ with $f(x_n)\to l$*:

Let $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(x)=\begin{cases}1, & x\neq0\\ 0, & x=0\end{cases}$. Then $\forall x\in\mathbb{R},\; \liminf_{y\to x}f(y)=1\geq f(x)$ and $f$ is l.s.c. Consider $x_n=\frac{1+(-1)^n}{2}\frac{1}{n}$ so that $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}=(0,\frac{1}{2},0,\frac{1}{4},0,\frac{1}{6},0,\dots)$. Clearly $0\leq x_n\leq \frac{1}{n}$ so $x_n\to 0$ yet $\big(f(x_n)\big)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}=(0,1,0,1,0,1,\dots)$ wich doesn't converge so $\lim_{n}f(x_n)\geq f(0)=0$ can't be true and $(*)$ is false.

---

Am I being asked to prove something that is false? Is the counter example correct? On the statement of the property, is it implied that $f(x_n)$ converges? (that is, the statement is meant to be interpreted as $\forall x\to x$ such that $f(x_n)$ converge, $\lim f(x_n)\geq f(x)$. In which case it seems to be true). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Btw, $\liminf_{y\to x}f(x)=\sup\{\inf\{f(y)\mid y\in B(x,\delta)\setminus\{x\}\}\mid \delta>0\}$.

Comment: It should be a function is lsc. **iff** for all $x_n \to x$, we have $\liminf_n f(x_n) \ge f(x)$. Not $\lim_n$.

Comment: Some authors define $\lim_{y\to x}f(x) = \lim_{\epsilon \downarrow 0} \inf_{y \in B(x,\epsilon)} f(y)$.